# JSZip Read Zip File and Execute from an Existing Zip File

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jszip

I've been using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to read and write zip files in Javascript.

What I'm trying to do is load a web app (index.html, style.css, image files, and whatever else the user requires for their web app) compressed in a zip file from a `input[type=file]` element (I'm using FileReader to read the contents of the zip file and display the files/folders on the page)

```
// Show contents
var $result = $(".result");
$("#file").on("change", function(evt) {
  // remove content
  $result.html("");
  // be sure to show the results
  $(".result_block").removeClass("hide");

  // see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

  var files = evt.target.files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        var $title = $("<h4>", {
          text : theFile.name
        });
        $result.append($title);
        var $fileContent = $("<ul>");
        try {

          var dateBefore = new Date();
          // read the content of the file with JSZip
          var zip = new JSZip(e.target.result);
          var dateAfter = new Date();

          $title.append($("<span>", {
            text:" (parsed in " + (dateAfter - dateBefore) + "ms)"
          }));
          $(".check").removeClass("hide");

          // that, or a good ol' for(var entryName in zip.files)
          $.each(zip.files, function (index, zipEntry) {
            $fileContent.append($("<li>", {
              text : zipEntry.name
            }));
            // the content is here : zipEntry.asText()
          });
          // end of the magic !
        } catch(e) {
          $fileContent = $("<div>", {
            "class" : "alert alert-danger",
            text : "Error reading " + theFile.name + " : " + e.message
          });
        }
        $result.append($fileContent);
      }
    })(f);

    // read the file !
    // readAsArrayBuffer and readAsBinaryString both produce valid content for JSZip.
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    $(".check").removeClass("hide").addClass("hide");
    // reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  }
});
```

Then when I click on say the Linux icon I want to export my web app as a native Linux app. I do this by using [JSZipUtils](https://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/)/[JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). I'm loading a zip file named `YourLinApp.zip` which has all the files necessary for the user to run their web app as a native Linux app. All that's missing in this zip file is their source code.

I trigger this using the following function...

```
// Download as Linux App
$(".export-as-lin-app").on("click", function() {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("YourLinApp.zip", function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      throw err; // or handle err
    }

    var zip = new JSZip(data);

    // Your Web App
    zip.file("source.c", "/*\n  Save this file as main.c and compile it using this command\n  (those are backticks, not single quotes):\n    gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0` -export-dynamic\n  \n  Then execute it using:\n  ./main\n  \n  If you can't compile chances are you don't have gcc installed.\n  Install gcc/c with the following terminal command. (This command is for Debian based Linux distros)\n    sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libglib2.0-doc\n  \n  WebKit requires libraries to successfully aquire, configure, and compile. You can get libraries by issuing the following command in your terminal:\n    sudo apt-get install subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev\n  \n  Ubuntu Webkit information - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit\n    sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev python-webkit-dev python-webkit\n  \n  Required dependencies for this build: (If you installed all the above this is not needed)\n    sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libglib2.0-doc subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev libwebkitgtk-dev\n*/\n\n#include <limits.h>\n#include <gtk/gtk.h>\n#include <webkit/webkit.h>\n\nstatic GtkWidget* window;\nstatic WebKitWebView* web_view;\n\nstatic void destroy_cb (GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {\n  gtk_main_quit();\n}\n\nstatic GtkWidget* create_browser() {\n  GtkWidget* scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);\n  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);\n\n  web_view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webkit_web_view_new ());\n  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), GTK_WIDGET (web_view));\n\n  return scrolled_window;\n}\n\nint main (int argc, char* argv[]) {\n  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);\n\n  GtkWidget* vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);\n  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), create_browser(), TRUE, TRUE, 0);\n\n  GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);\n  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 800, 560);\n  gtk_widget_set_name (window, \"" + $('.projectname').val() + "\");\n  /* gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(window, \"app/logo.png\", NULL); */\n  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), \"destroy\", G_CALLBACK (destroy_cb), NULL);\n  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);\n  \n  char uri[PATH_MAX];\n  char cwd[PATH_MAX];\n\n  getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));\n\n  if (argc > 1)\n      snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), \"%s\", argv[1]);\n  else\n      snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), \"file://%s/" + $('.projectname').val() + "/app/index.html\", cwd);\n  \n  webkit_web_view_open (web_view, uri);\n\n  gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (web_view));\n  gtk_widget_show_all (window);\n  gtk_main ();\n\n  return 0;\n}\n");
    zip.file("README", "This application for Linux relies on the following dependencies...\n  sudo apt-get install subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev\n\nIf kodeWeave was at all helpful for you. Would you consider donating to the project?\nhttps://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=BSYGA2RB5ZJCC\n\n");
    var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
    saveAs(content, "lin-export.zip");
    return false;
  });
});
```

My problem is merging their source code in with the new zip file, while still having the freedom to add files into the zip file using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

I know [JSZip can read zip files](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html), but haven't been able to get it to work for my needs.

I can either add files to the loaded zip file using `zip.file(name, code)` or add files (`using zip.file(name, code)`) to the data of the zip file I'm using to convert the web app to a desktop app. The problem here is it doesn't load the files from the `input[type=file]` aka FileReader.

Here's my jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Detect if users browser can load and download files in Javascript
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Detect if users browser can download files in Javascript
  } else {
    alert("The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
  }

  // Show error if zip is corrupted
  if (!window.FileReader || !window.ArrayBuffer) {
    $(".error_block").removeClass("hide");
    return;
  }

  // Show contents
  var $result = $(".result");
  $("#file").on("change", function(evt) {
    // remove content
    $result.html("");
    // be sure to show the results
    $(".result_block").removeClass("hide");

    // see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          var $title = $("<h4>", {
            text : theFile.name
          });
          $result.append($title);
          var $fileContent = $("<ul>");
          try {

            var dateBefore = new Date();
            // read the content of the file with JSZip
            var zip = new JSZip(e.target.result);
            var dateAfter = new Date();

            $title.append($("<span>", {
              text:" (parsed in " + (dateAfter - dateBefore) + "ms)"
            }));
            $(".check").removeClass("hide");

            // that, or a good ol' for(var entryName in zip.files)
            $.each(zip.files, function (index, zipEntry) {
              $fileContent.append($("<li>", {
                text : zipEntry.name
              }));
              // the content is here : zipEntry.asText()
            });
            // end of the magic !
          } catch(e) {
            $fileContent = $("<div>", {
              "class" : "alert alert-danger",
              text : "Error reading " + theFile.name + " : " + e.message
            });
          }
          $result.append($fileContent);

          // Download as Linux App
          $(".export-as-lin-app").on("click", function() {
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("YourLinApp.zip", function(err, data) {
              if(err) {
                throw err; // or handle err
              }

              var zip = new JSZip(data);

              // Your Web App
              zip.file("source.c", "/*\n  Save this file as main.c and compile it using this command\n  (those are backticks, not single quotes):\n    gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0` -export-dynamic\n  \n  Then execute it using:\n  ./main\n  \n  If you can't compile chances are you don't have gcc installed.\n  Install gcc/c with the following terminal command. (This command is for Debian based Linux distros)\n    sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libglib2.0-doc\n  \n  WebKit requires libraries to successfully aquire, configure, and compile. You can get libraries by issuing the following command in your terminal:\n    sudo apt-get install subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev\n  \n  Ubuntu Webkit information - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit\n    sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev python-webkit-dev python-webkit\n  \n  Required dependencies for this build: (If you installed all the above this is not needed)\n    sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libglib2.0-doc subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev libwebkitgtk-dev\n*/\n\n#include <limits.h>\n#include <gtk/gtk.h>\n#include <webkit/webkit.h>\n\nstatic GtkWidget* window;\nstatic WebKitWebView* web_view;\n\nstatic void destroy_cb (GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {\n  gtk_main_quit();\n}\n\nstatic GtkWidget* create_browser() {\n  GtkWidget* scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);\n  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);\n\n  web_view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webkit_web_view_new ());\n  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), GTK_WIDGET (web_view));\n\n  return scrolled_window;\n}\n\nint main (int argc, char* argv[]) {\n  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);\n\n  GtkWidget* vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);\n  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), create_browser(), TRUE, TRUE, 0);\n\n  GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);\n  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 800, 560);\n  gtk_widget_set_name (window, \"" + $('.projectname').val() + "\");\n  /* gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(window, \"app/logo.png\", NULL); */\n  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), \"destroy\", G_CALLBACK (destroy_cb), NULL);\n  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);\n  \n  char uri[PATH_MAX];\n  char cwd[PATH_MAX];\n\n  getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));\n\n  if (argc > 1)\n      snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), \"%s\", argv[1]);\n  else\n      snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), \"file://%s/" + $('.projectname').val() + "/app/index.html\", cwd);\n  \n  webkit_web_view_open (web_view, uri);\n\n  gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (web_view));\n  gtk_widget_show_all (window);\n  gtk_main ();\n\n  return 0;\n}\n");
              zip.file("README", "This application for Linux relies on the following dependencies...\n  sudo apt-get install subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev\n\nIf kodeWeave was at all helpful for you. Would you consider donating to the project?\nhttps://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=BSYGA2RB5ZJCC\n\n");
              var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
              saveAs(content, "lin-export.zip");
              return false;
            });
          });

        }
      })(f);

      // read the file !
      // readAsArrayBuffer and readAsBinaryString both produce valid content for JSZip.
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
      $(".check").removeClass("hide").addClass("hide");
      // reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: In your code, you don't really use the FileReader : you print the content of the selected class, then you add an event handler on `.export-as-lin-app` (which won't be executed because it needs a click to be triggered). Are you trying to update the selected file (then regenerate it) ? In that case, `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("YourLinApp.zip"` is useless here : use directly the previous zip object.

Comment: I updated the question for better understanding. I added the application source code on github - https://github.com/mikethedj4/WebDGap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSZip.load` merges the content : if you load the given zip file and `YourLinApp.zip` you will merge the content.

```
// read the content with a FileReader
var originalZipContent = e.target.result;
// ...
$(".export-as-lin-app").on("click", function() {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("YourLinApp.zip", function(err, data) {

    // merge two files
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.load(data);
    zip.load(originalZipContent)

    var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
    saveAs(content, "lin-export.zip");
  }
});
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/dduponchel/WebDGap/commit/7e7eaad7315d99051e6bfe32b455cbdfb1a67b1a) for a working example.

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of that. Thank you so much bro.